# Why won't my GPIO pins setup correctly with RPi.GPIO?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am really worried I may have fried my GPIO because even this super simple code results in an error

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
import time

io.setmode(io.BCM)

io.setup(12, io.OUT)

while True:
    try:
        io.output(12, 1)
    finally:
        io.cleanup()
```

Running this results in:
    RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT
(this happens on the line "io.output(12, 1)"

....is my GPIO fried? I can't understand why this super simple GPIO code would not work....this happens no matter what pin I choose to setup...

Comment: A fried GPIO wouldn't output such errors, it'll either silently fail and not react to your code or the chip handling it would be totally dead and your RPi wouldn't even start.

Comment: Have you loaded the correct kernel modules ? Did this code work before ?

Comment: I have the module loaded correctly. I have used this same approach before, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, good news...My GPIO works just fine!

The problem was that I had the try/finally blocks inside of the while block, instead of the while block inside of the try block. What was happening is that the io.cleanup() method gets called, removing the setup of the GPIO pin, then the io.output(12, 1) runs, without being setup! Problem solved.